# How do I make my django application perform a job at a fixed time everyday?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, celery, django-celery

Some tuples in my database need to be erased after a given time. I need my django app to check if the rows have expired.

While I can definitely write the function, how do I make Django run at everyday at a fixed time?

I have heard about Task Queues like Celery. Are they too much powerful for this? Is their anything simpler? May be something build-in?

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple cron job to trigger a custom Django management command.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `threading.Thread` to schedule a continuous event loop. In your thread, use `time.sleep` to create a gap before the next occurrence of the event.

Comment: IMO, thread based approach is a resource hog - management commands or some schedulers like redis, etc are better.